# Transferring money that was just deposited

Tags: transfer

I just deposited a few checks to a new savings and checking account at the same bank but I realize the amount I wanted in both were wrong. I want to transfer from my savings to checking but there's currently $0.00 in there since the deposit hasn't gone through. Can I go ahead an schedule a transfer immediately, or do I have to wait until the money has gone through?

Comment: What do you mean by "the amount I wanted in both were wrong"? Did you enter incorrect amount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how your bank handles it.
Typically, they allow you to access only a limited amount of your deposits *the same day*; for a new customer, that might be even zero.

However, you should be able to control the full amount the *next business day*.

If they don't allow you access today, you wouldn't be able to submit a transfer online; it doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: Question is about *new* accounts, there likely will be a considerably longer delay before availability.